# how to set the on tap event of dojox.mobile.listitem?

Tags: mobile, dojo

I have tried the following with no luck.

```
<li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='onClick:compassHeading'>
    Compass Heading
</li>
```

it will pop a parser error.

how to set the on tap event of dojox.mobile.listitem in dojo mobile?

Comment: What does the parser error say?

Comment: it is a error{} from dojo parser

Comment: Maybe you could just hook up a listener with dojo/on